# AngularJS changing {{post.title}} to Another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to change the value of `{{post.title}}` in my HTML to open another html file.

```
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <h2>
            {{post.title}}
                <a ng-click="editPost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                <a ng-click="deletePost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
            </h2>
            <em>{{post.posted}}</em>
            <p>{{post.body}}</p>
        </div>
```

[image]

**Location of .html files:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this,

```
 <a  ng-click="redirect()">{{ post.title }} </a>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.redirect = function(){
  window.location = "#/titleDetails.html";
}
```

Comment: do I have to add in server.js as well?

Comment: what is server.js? no need

Answer (score 1):

You can have an added property for destination url in post and have this

```
<a href="{{'#'+post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
```

if you are sure about the url u can put the value for url yourself

```
<a href="#destinationpage">{{post.title}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    <a href="#" ng-click="ClickMeToRedirect()">{{ post.title }}</a>


var app = angular.module('urlApp', []);
app.controller('urlCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $window) {
    $scope.ClickMeToRedirect = function () {
        var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/titleDetails.html";
        $log.log(url);
        $window.location.href = url;
    };
});
```

OR

```
var url = "#/titleDetails.html";
```